# creating D3 Word Cloud by using an array of json objects instead of reading from json file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am quite new to D3 and I have a D3 word cloud template that reads from a json file and then creates a word cloud. The part that reads from json file and inputs the keys and values into chart is :

```
d3.json("testdata.json", data => {
   var chart = renderChart()
    .svgHeight(600)
    .container('#myGraph')
    .data({ values: data })
    .responsive(true)
    .run()
})
```

What I wish to do is populate this word cloud from an array of json objects that are created by the program dynamically during the program execution that is why I cannot write it into a json file manually.

One of the many codes that I tried to use was this:

```
test =>{
    var chart = renderChart()
    .svgHeight(600)
    .container('#myGraph')
    .data({ values: test})
    .responsive(true)
    .run()
    }
```

where test is my array of json objects. 
The code is working with no errors but it is displaying nothing.

Any help much appreciated !

Comment: The code to configure `renderChart` seems fine. Maybe you forget to invoke the arrow function that takes the `test` object and render the chart.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! code has to be:

```
var chart = renderChart()
    .svgHeight(600)
    .container('#myGraph')
    .data({ values: test})
    .responsive(true)
    .run()
```